# Having issues opening Deployd dashboard

Tags: angularjs, node.js, deployd

I am a beginner with Deployd (**www.deployd.com**). I am learning the book "Pro AngularJS" and I have followed at the beginning of chapter 6 all the instructions in order to open the Deployd dashboard in the browser but am getting errors at the command prompt and the dashboard's refuses to open in the browser.

The page keeps on loading till it stops and displays that the server is not found. I also followed the steps on [Deployd](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-api.html)'s page and I still get the same errors.

The error I receive at the prompt is:

```
 Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
    at C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\lib\db.js:262:8
    at C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\lib\db.js:155:12
    at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node_modules\bl
uebird\js\main\util.js:24:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\
deployd\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:454:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\n
ode_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:530:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\no
de_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:646:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node_mod
ules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:79:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node_mo
dules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:89:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\Deployd\n
ode_modules\deployd\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:14:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
    at C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\lib\db.js:262:8
    at C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\lib\db.js:155:12
    at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node_modules\bl
uebird\js\main\util.js:24:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\
deployd\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:454:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\n
ode_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:530:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\no
de_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:646:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node_mod
ules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:79:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\Deployd\node_modules\deployd\node_mo
dules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:89:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\Deployd\n
ode_modules\deployd\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:14:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
```

Note: any time I type a command at the Deployd console I get the following message at the prompt:

```
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

before the results of the prompt appears.  I don't know if it is also part of the problem. It is my first time trying to use Deployd so I have no clue what these errors mean.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bson installation. If you have not noticed the bson errors in red letters in the console while installing

```
npm install deployd -g
```

try update with,

```
npm update
```

To get the bson package correctly installed in your system you need, python and c++ compilers in the right path in your system.
Here is the link that shows many options to get the bson package installed properly. 
http://techtothepoint.blogspot.com/2015/03/npm-install-errors-buildreleasebson.html